# Making a protocol that's conformers implement a subclass of a class

Tags: swift

I am using SpriteKit and I have a protocol "Node" that is the top level object in which all my classes conform to. Im trying to figure out a way to declare that Nodes children must conform to some class that conforms to SKNode.

For example, I have another protocol SpriteNode that would conform to Node and SKSpiteNode. I tried achieving this my doing:

```
protocol Node: SKNode {}

protocol SpriteNode: SKSpiteNode, Node {}
```

I got an error though as I suspect I cannot extend two classes basically.

I've also spent a lot of time looking where clauses and associated types but I can't quite figure out the one I'd need to use or if this is even possible without using generics and classes.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Are you certain the above code actually generates a problem (after fixing your typo of "SKSpiteNode" for "SKSpriteNode")?

Comment: Once you attempt to make a class that conforms to SpriteNode it generates the error

Comment: Can you demonstrate that problem? I don't see that either. `class S: SKSpriteNode, SpriteNode {}` works fine.

Comment: Oh, why do I have to put SKSpriteNode, that did work: thanks.

Comment: Requiring a class inheritance doesn't inject that class inheritance. If it did, it would be ambiguous if you conformed to multiple protocols.

Comment: Okay thank you, this is what I misunderstood